# Open file in python(command open)

Tags: python, file-io

I'm doing a online course to program in python. I must read contents of file in a list. I wrote the code below.The program works but when I submit my work to the site, it gives me the message below. Do you know what would be the problem? Thank you

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str
    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.

    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """

    words_file=open(words_file)
    los=[]
    for line in words_file:
        if '\n' in line:
            line=line[:len(line)-1]
        los.append(line)
    return (los)
```

Method Description:
None

Message:
ERROR: DisabledBuiltinError

Calling the open built-in is not permitted.

Comment: the website isn't going to let you call open() for security reasons. If it works on your machine, just submit it as is.

Comment: Unless the error message appears because the assignment specifically says you're not allowed to use `open()`, of course.

Comment: Please close your file objects! Either use a context manager (`with open(words_file) as words_file:` and indent everything once) or use `words_file.close()` at the bottom of your code

Comment: You should read the rules of submitting work to the site. I can easily imagine that they are providing you with the input data in some special way for example through `sys.stdin` but I don't like guessing, read the docs.

Comment: If the course is any good, you could ask in the discussion forum there for more specific help.